# How to get a readable scale on a particular R plot?

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

I already made a post for this question on biostars forum (https://www.biostars.org/p/452352/) but did not get a lot of replies.

I'm having difficulties to get a plot with a readable scale.

I have plotted transcriptomic data using R with package EMA. However 'genes names' (ordinate axis) are written too big and I can't see all gene names. I would like to have one gene name per compartment.

[image: plot picture]

Here is my code:

```
clustering.plot(tree= c.sample, tree.sup=c.gene, data=tpm.100,
                dendro=TRUE, dendro.sup=TRUE, names=TRUE, names.sup=TRUE, names.dist=TRUE, trim.heatmap=0.99)

clustering.plot(tree= c.sample, tree.sup=c.gene, data=tpm.100,
                legend=FALSE, legend.pos="bottomright",
                dendro=FALSE, dendro.sup=FALSE,names.sup=TRUE, names.dist=TRUE,trim.heatmap=0.99)
```

I have read EMA package documentation to play with different options without success.

I'm new with R, there should be some obvious things i'm missing

What can I do? Thank you for your help

#EDIT dataset : tpm.100

```
""  "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N"
"LF2"   4.37251830280457    3.79337725046113    5.8250224504098 2.30957747745382    3.08873420659215    13.3845479391399    7.76189989467388    11.1917453986345    11.1499547797979    3.50848101796127    9.35082031987687    11.8092563942256    9.39724269010983    13.4332344012444
"EBNA-2"    12.8224558812328    12.0941500941692    15.988446711091 15.5203507138597    12.8903272040782    6.91729981008852    15.0404654572831    10.6780332384752    8.95432143980119    12.1414532204521    7.6323858075834 6.64751282673952    15.6987694735917    6.76982578248166
"LF3"   8.07288917658948    7.97217547871547    9.79184933859188    6.58792988904478    7.3123454856477 16.6208191486017    10.901403777756 10.7274513449236    14.1317626267484    8.03487961798245    12.3212304233878    15.4913892648681    10.5819483113427    15.4673569645312
"BHLF1" 16.8502732931535    16.8228581644784    11.0084088547388    9.51803772433279    16.2354205034282    10.4807477004206    14.6013477258031    12.9317467467272    11.3819039979617    17.0700682716697    11.4125724312503    11.2362127205754    12.8594916420447    11.2177499746744
"BFLF2" 13.4608208944838    13.5809913239752    6.99399231525033    5.36119926988005    13.4343314303174    13.4446872289686    11.4340642063672    9.34882889778184    10.1894668679053    13.2903078260655    9.45616459875228    11.3867471077814    9.8371751543237 13.1409545204513
"BLLF3" 11.4215890710942    11.8339658274478    6.17859136742252    4.23668308631416    11.5657481645114    11.9511676437658    9.08281262963373    6.47345090537718    8.81225002908133    11.6329496058154    7.50405842940241    9.86776990859038    8.4151529506793 11.5774278049559
"BSLF1" 11.4830932574661    11.4509550927501    5.71744600231917    4.31511410615241    11.2526939629061    11.7018322264504    9.28957725146196    7.25698263735948    8.4368304540121 10.9024391210252    7.32902066601871    9.78770043144742    8.06847012410754    10.9711033550742
"BDLF3" 15.0640166535793    15.4359210666724    7.49081416247697    6.42672761359542    15.1678365466212    14.4752480585655    12.1021415925091    11.3527435413787    12.8673824103585    15.0379397207531    11.4322369669153    13.5035860091829    11.4235897623221    15.033636955724
"BDLF2" 14.645161799132 14.8291230461073    7.17778489332052    6.04643183580975    14.5775957188173    13.8639590940418    11.5490028490375    10.9744593215665    12.4332202070541    14.7345037335209    10.9158992802533    12.9235848310228    10.9360360979946    14.3320713797249
"BdRF1" 14.6300840992101    14.6808535619118    9.70588084675716    8.52715882378042    14.3725022407391    15.1284558301654    12.0621457234822    10.783745051373 13.4212394971342    14.4119729461578    11.6739985229609    13.8366943163353    10.7008541032657    14.9323658489796
"BVRF2" 13.9363889368577    13.9832708609902    9.10544827534997    7.99151418663244    13.6374449292   14.4239976743599    11.3721870369945    10.1042302773056    12.7324981580645    13.6823471320035    10.9879584445416    13.128672687505 9.97538715911899    14.2494738903406
"LF1"   7.37347055160352    7.21586110457839    5.85731583915565    3.03103012216689    6.40418220550588    12.7406911121563    7.83885294725129    8.98762059716084    10.5044103795497    6.64117651233047    8.59326067410317    11.2312309802997    9.80085456830385    12.7078110227725
"BDLF1" 14.2298675354375    14.3512352813815    6.67068212866131    5.7760600216764 14.1587885853384    13.5866786105099    11.2508981523845    10.7492829214157    12.066906446019 14.4285754412389    10.5103997514352    12.5179976415627    10.2433937880859    13.9062206406208
"BFLF1" 12.1909567128106    12.170986655086 5.79858742171722    4.08457220768075    11.8034118551008    11.8455481979796    9.8456975609416 8.22868587508723    8.61386008722957    11.6699785063028    7.79510118273341    9.78505649862906    8.31071371075477    11.4391512097919
"BALF2" 12.4195849401503    12.4393331043235    7.15030405460852    6.77004503467537    13.1715367105801    13.5297487227477    11.0652960175896    9.26855960853991    10.4540557787732    13.1721615670981    9.36239165733958    11.8970332170916    9.86671635104554    13.1792915785353
"BILF2" 13.5450358447842    13.6516512258258    6.00382881485026    5.07315648593401    13.5574239482946    12.8253051745896    10.5970217921361    10.1592534495087    11.6094273190347    13.6743886169599    10.0392998847289    12.3495115812258    9.92367652694556    13.848971475521
"BDLF3.5"   12.0194826101976    12.1873990109322    6.05465519915957    3.77330127635333    11.4656510202535    12.3419666708778    8.32328573170721    8.1945847833941 10.5128462664389    11.5571988258961    8.84629717977968    11.4256559693168    9.37341654551581    13.1682327095981
"BVLF1" 11.2584470931878    11.1512775208181    4.64304484219212    3.38891387896081    9.60292364093599    10.817283759417 8.25309208617759    7.42384031107179    9.43092623695213    9.59602624617947    7.29345671491331    10.3797929379028    6.04439095686912    11.9956681522574
"BcLF1" 13.6003759774044    13.6183055841485    6.70693169726706    5.085941363805  13.4286436387982    13.8073405259498    10.7540413520744    10.1427217709832    12.105090975387 13.3774955050003    10.4973464357819    12.7719075958458    9.80888840375117    13.9297085214842
"BSLF2/BMLF1"   13.9039252721659    14.2322663029217    8.89066653096137    6.63851967128496    14.6986736475745    14.5226170505485    12.5311507107947    10.6410327548338    10.9200698979651    13.9586861056721    10.2920413819124    12.6521944680217    10.6339420978185    13.5879715693544
"BBLF2/BBLF3"   11.950300557113 12.1619602447135    6.69125355104806    4.79191730775496    12.8696576205451    13.0142815389708    9.92648869793656    8.81684607874448    9.80478936866043    12.4382803271852    8.70396063855999    11.098201444281 9.88218299046271    12.5354285310106
"BGLF2" 13.3623710691706    13.4104788785005    6.36023942742874    4.67943919044099    13.2842576052787    13.4565485920281    10.4564735856502    9.6150583249492 11.7333941170842    13.2134602569537    10.0960904546458    12.3860318827375    10.0294501463452    13.8198559321966
"BALF1" 10.5145193960372    10.4410002216072    5.87053303999058    7.1405781515786 11.1537820550881    11.6853191176866    8.9966262431786 6.4385977758241 8.30882057288123    10.2912168623372    7.46234325599958    9.94802608324567    6.7390578829886 10.7058067428639
"BMRF1" 14.1152182507594    14.2927562452732    10.5857940111977    8.37601004271499    14.2450973424259    14.2760251737669    12.8396541290431    10.2496270833946    11.5555638533083    14.1469725183779    10.6486335836721    12.9185209250317    11.8658979353826    14.0424412359552
"BMRF2" 14.2177298266499    14.3639097849643    10.4068951472432    8.36734302344797    14.3121897032098    14.2759857696733    12.8096591734831    10.2612887910671    11.4714295625048    14.1227579615761    10.7815472122573    12.8608407919042    11.9472799931969    13.9827331411507
"BZLF2" 14.4805808139649    14.6421143390049    6.13497132042548    5.81978385563811    14.5364487082944    11.9052540379064    11.3278400857649    11.4559461331552    11.0220347960826    14.4420169532726    9.80185696121673    11.6776026536966    10.6451850521319    12.5249289824521
"BZLF1" 12.519623215858 13.1951817657834    10.7686005074345    8.60524022199654    13.7851035772226    13.7549985480837    13.3579807523923    9.85307187869064    10.3714382413353    12.8866463853012    9.58641997452154    11.9983717157811    9.76924052751454    13.2067051855369
"BLLF2" 15.4980338343419    15.7201529312808    8.18413474735602    7.00983897711864    14.9533790473633    14.1321240082301    12.082195319275 11.5929613803653    12.4913566389436    15.2791010266154    11.2698030070434    13.1825845298884    11.6666510247968    14.4573742613165
"BGLF5" 12.4475700704094    12.6705933307583    6.77277776126228    4.91929640848377    13.2838319430579    13.6086969257822    10.5826718243184    9.40478275442196    10.4664528501335    12.7389586853993    9.3439720829389 11.7425040811136    9.90238356453211    13.0864233963949
"BGLF1" 11.8539332320053    11.8630135661487    5.16799491803662    3.2291441162384 11.6755639419767    12.1783719568108    9.0072924339344 7.99658971329771    10.1880444858947    11.5058321749303    8.65003570960647    11.0834721492857    8.89664443832515    12.7172877556998
"BXLF2" 12.5187508251637    12.5969553089217    6.34485416176162    4.07805742274939    11.9661718470134    12.9583140769234    9.63173422160519    9.1154896943838 10.8617823628509    12.0123511957027    9.32332220944915    11.731344918066 9.29206180758426    13.3612609507892
"BBRF3" 13.2782291852478    13.4108533476912    8.98099332974592    7.35271592330286    12.8353036949027    11.7744136784012    10.4003172379057    9.09209303697224    10.8966727268655    12.6061092344397    9.47549353061731    11.1841390071327    13.4179658471436    12.3950477813942
"BBLF1" 13.0893890407004    13.4847311678738    6.77126314633267    5.67073007186654    13.9339279591337    13.8937059020232    10.9645771269205    10.8022426362681    11.1822256642812    13.3007152872928    10.0025799752468    12.1222967935072    10.2238367591034    13.6711228231494
"BXLF1" 11.7553516878836    11.7318039140301    6.04230639513059    3.73375274438081    10.8339672039083    12.3788214826212    8.91133402561086    8.30733122432098    10.1424597389107    11.1157388154746    8.44641249962152    11.0783329597857    8.72045786563361    12.8195710740706
"BRLF1" 11.129122324012 11.4810656385613    4.98989078628398    3.90250260694187    11.2298688844237    11.8497412300212    9.08155567804356    8.16752124280478    8.92459117338834    10.6455291944735    7.52063635237617    9.874736855908  8.1637746926525 11.2370060487585
"BORF1" 13.2984306278184    13.2890055786176    9.37454697384844    7.72741596927339    13.1435195439407    13.4722757186152    10.9984358690712    9.70579239407929    11.1811235689284    13.3963492037452    10.0290745778053    11.9289424250264    11.1270748534511    13.2222683025578
"BFRF1" 13.5181839262851    13.4399655837393    8.84581798880857    7.54591289650281    13.0323131640914    13.3178674409401    10.7604866449453    9.07543945214957    11.6755717461234    13.4593662138162    10.6778584080796    12.1341301460724    10.2114053712997    13.2989399650273
"BWRF1" 14.0221542694012    13.2336707826122    17.2164890984615    16.0720598996948    14.0276366011152    15.3196787104397    16.2514940922214    11.7514779204362    17.4803333913642    13.4310897192916    17.5228686240165    17.2328204752755    16.2958286455045    15.825478891253
"BLLF1" 15.0334176969077    15.3067888767315    7.22761018162599    6.22310739057758    14.3971971442452    13.2147641480279    11.5314630446742    11.4075258751472    11.6546005376432    14.704391267564 10.4789385348   12.4459496587056    11.1940508198194    13.6261039146549
"BBLF4" 10.3781228604334    10.3924133017154    4.95156739045728    3.57725764212247    10.3610016228666    11.3340838788582    7.81071308383399    7.29953819795517    8.28575057039054    9.72259345201645    6.98155638478844    9.37086624259683    8.32691295983762    11.1529776011868
"BGLF4" 12.0131603467224    12.1659398674569    6.00963376377409    4.40342021801119    12.3764768084727    12.8314148062109    9.84743953227221    9.07087058739648    9.8495025051728 12.1771322390386    8.51352760456339    10.9937736221694    9.71270672645772    12.5714265933354
"BKRF4" 14.9581943439483    15.2291781629769    10.7693982258595    9.88256887718171    15.3874808499906    14.5790158371231    12.6754501211404    11.6796764611869    13.0068467574717    15.292962896562 11.6749681742731    13.6198735979011    14.3498535175597    14.5211760924503
"LMP-1" 13.8363365697641    13.3613161858941    15.038190636159 17.4040773659747    14.8207183832178    12.1529208364776    16.4612920246754    12.2936926627454    10.8255927391312    14.4883072177695    11.0078872757718    11.6849197274184    16.3259842545345    12.0151435949376
"BFRF3" 14.4357939272614    14.3850811557202    9.12655057876074    7.69330817450036    14.363531477278 13.9001249023181    12.2039179361338    10.839400867878 12.2302791746019    14.6218971482511    11.1252963576017    12.8669660195533    12.0105549445283    13.7608125470669
"BORF2" 13.7847905352146    13.6476908035678    9.78653265635389    7.9893477840498 13.674995087149 14.2461128522373    11.6472019847568    10.0965772343537    11.5793297265902    13.9197762959431    10.609663102241 12.5909970954446    11.2617061611682    13.6619677497167
"EBNA-LP"   14.5094290920931    13.5950158771815    17.9373361531585    17.1649008990777    14.5778999410817    15.9963954633167    16.3850007501793    12.3998508924688    17.8384077299256    14.4889102206759    18.0331403652695    17.5021273682608    17.0565606827836    16.1282633246753
"BDLF4" 11.6668972248964    11.7873131042084    5.49657962826022    2.93240173383099    11.2045744448637    11.9720525021949    8.66197916636122    8.6607019320674 9.96974357375614    11.0973431114032    8.31446042273025    10.8770369180613    8.96310062490054    12.6565018157728
"BGLF3.5"   12.1593941737835    12.2311883832087    5.37524358099535    3.75904157795662    12.4508365416615    12.7487088839974    9.63798940710171    9.37098835205305    9.88053834491713    12.2038980807986    8.41686857163979    11.0740256951291    9.4193362424188 12.6958501121303
"BALF4" 13.1419159025876    13.042888739016 9.48697068801813    7.32257138136308    12.6983191859201    13.0299741524318    11.2551737898631    11.364387828299 11.191758187223 12.4714736289101    9.71708612004277    11.6477616131993    9.77044002648233    13.0864948411916
"BKRF3" 14.2032255361488    14.2895068140996    10.1880029773147    9.34430804493519    14.595565461366 13.8727854379658    12.0644014804608    10.7943854675412    12.3655040209872    14.5710422349542    11.0470527851782    13.0240404476908    13.8789043405814    13.6930141737916
"BFRF1A"    13.0239868395962    12.8820993273369    8.851096467179  7.62352732816523    12.4749866670829    12.9584138809714    10.2650564597429    9.03791017689911    11.3944096975071    12.8320854613489    10.6633924532184    11.6955567599618    9.98300618038534    12.9527025192924
"BPLF1" 11.8779196463569    11.7101714770953    5.17923448156262    3.73908091728442    10.217113998085 9.67783495087775    7.93566922272801    7.36943182445607    8.07415724777891    10.5968982419998    6.55822047267264    8.82635145828855    7.27835862534265    9.74939061281017
"BLRF2" 14.101434017487 14.2460107887958    9.97218502571758    9.02316545517408    14.7042674138773    13.2347728394793    12.3894947110435    10.9066492103837    11.8626479307725    14.6057093651385    10.9091757351203    12.2873774761815    11.6163911023694    13.1421024628289
"BFRF2" 13.3988079919312    13.3081517444225    8.40871782164266    7.04298630693978    12.9660460186153    13.060932923608 10.8517475993511    9.02065413416408    11.3363821782634    13.353465138035 10.2212840436243    11.8447930090119    10.9777040156183    13.0530107326361
"BVRF1" 11.2988827700704    11.2324958705448    7.65758485613537    6.82171547026683    10.5519514241837    11.6065093765528    8.83459355295613    8.55903351071563    10.2491258714323    10.8009156812984    8.48702878758268    10.5173594622037    7.3652313419889 11.5955108151115
"BLRF1" 13.3269011186985    13.4675635342861    10.0463112790876    9.14424260051657    13.6058904556418    12.334868197167 11.4367105012718    7.92786033428452    11.4033257716271    13.4418923973025    10.4376432466363    11.6847608049531    11.4602842309167    12.8975368126299
"BHRF1" 14.253224610855 13.980715077419 15.1218305308819    15.5403819875485    14.6725237642832    16.7475525214221    15.5945638078695    12.5072513123843    18.439849143621 14.0131729612974    18.5464042578765    18.0558281251378    15.1627845714218    16.9337568533765
"BGLF3" 10.7285696811171    10.842247905875 4.02994503482535    2.76695076022337    10.3610388006675    10.6546666402622    8.0537888202123 8.06424509242489    8.43812624646238    10.3679990479899    6.98063036808677    9.48749327972435    8.73870953974285    10.7737422228938
"BILF1" 9.67979507461443    9.59049129242362    6.98186611500778    4.76273470925685    8.26256011492499    12.8144178938835    8.58376539075964    8.33165484132083    10.2353154179914    8.63597127975514    8.32784483900478    11.0712094684453    11.0502456169207    12.7975010039741
"RPMS1" 13.8911584420085    13.2111753135968    16.0802898990108    13.4014870275666    13.7452765187027    11.9744052235592    15.8072516441656    16.7236090998929    12.5807725610741    13.7555192690697    11.828318032638 11.7645378948297    14.8789219472393    11.6721179720909
"BCRF1.1"   10.4633813313568    10.523634636832 5.23603104966716    4.3968996292901 8.93112269974998    7.55278835041371    6.80685413153566    7.45530399068733    5.94676264253062    9.02970015357969    4.2204739611152 6.81171905677054    6.53678832787235    7.30071834920685
"BOLF1" 11.7523510131045    11.3861391315365    5.6663474007744 3.8599853338514 9.60336400126935    9.47531258769194    7.68415930765596    7.36268064455151    7.49787320576684    9.79570086547696    6.25224194801195    8.31948347914021    7.15222896865236    9.15061700971909
"A73"   15.1707601401788    14.8233423024058    17.4302081375097    14.7246155375155    14.5623637677622    13.2564693869433    16.5851208291714    17.5415337214298    13.4683729319225    14.8985051472883    12.9557634521613    12.7626930998141    15.4999568338412    12.8338083613847
"BXRF1" 11.3868161511054    11.2021612136006    9.60480615049878    7.16830076580365    10.3181280036061    11.0887710643221    8.75233319697803    6.12017082040728    10.4082385852702    10.5796274308928    9.17487151830344    10.2760491643278    6.62391303625027    11.3544616911367
"BARF0" 13.4196086075039    12.707561192615 15.1853797847026    12.5097722119748    13.1064993489849    11.5644702592517    15.2330727590537    15.8554868123753    11.4154326063908    13.0868350058141    10.8569610104558    10.953886770364 13.6013635942905    10.8197080319141
"BALF3" 12.4186593805434    11.8586325258206    10.2913684354405    7.86227076780212    11.0619877695394    11.487555367187 11.6512602302671    11.8469052704078    8.85062643471968    10.9503359415809    7.56833066128087    9.90687465508887    9.44999932686376    11.3044790376002
"BRRF2" 11.8530582416845    12.0090906429988    8.70936592844042    7.49290016892559    11.6111110072196    11.5736020732047    9.64065656304324    8.72016859733437    10.5874064678124    11.6858801838238    9.64589683460662    10.8121200983764    11.6589783889118    11.7529086452722
"BARF1.2"   10.1893685757045    10.1165006795364    7.99128447985966    6.91058501505408    10.7654367673785    9.99883786805724    9.20555299242449    8.37157343111392    8.90693507439191    10.1815423251985    7.37986561394391    9.08252054946554    5.5087160974939 9.80745890447346
"EBNA-3B/EBNA-3C"   13.6577819536416    13.8763886882739    12.8144070925741    10.7416507878708    10.1927706524147    8.32940828984798    11.7811420611792    7.992865382427  10.9177171412036    9.81968295467727    10.2974652360869    9.5744773169874 11.9468247516808    10.7675183508661
"BRRF1" 11.523862683888 11.8578914817611    8.93401645535641    8.01525766316903    11.4506235524292    11.911809485144 9.88092506334611    8.94019314939909    10.5707112636854    10.5904757922089    9.75405559378035    10.4470051451341    12.386819184416 12.3846804008292
"LMP-2B"    12.5127428639206    12.014504142403 13.963447958386 14.2461143117782    12.7214468973586    12.2070896146863    13.9573852178984    18.0421314352676    12.1398829332097    12.1833286010214    14.9357554302274    14.203248245257 15.0202315200856    13.8500436909897
"BBRF2" 12.0173723943176    11.9725990612981    9.49770654411359    8.31687190086296    11.0345667934862    11.0383939188241    9.91995544135413    8.16364258737046    10.4370843687665    10.7993619042373    9.09152875344965    10.1759779115972    13.6680727243191    11.6374442541826
"LMP-2A"    12.2614198633484    11.7731110232769    13.8505726895183    14.0291185484796    12.5726603310007    11.8848183306388    13.789917150239 17.6487402207548    11.8504170236588    12.0849808031166    14.5480972584652    13.8287577259728    14.6293621568884    13.4946968241985
"BKRF2" 12.8021842896225    12.9051838660956    10.703800816049 9.61544052807671    13.3534372605765    12.8442471492978    11.6986354007678    10.8822443388359    11.6019187813806    13.0127288056413    10.5436594068708    11.9545420961691    14.5705141248805    12.7297104727325
"BNLF2a"    14.90520388812  14.5648115953126    15.627420138679 17.9105169081198    15.9758768603297    14.7785511711824    16.9998898591266    13.1867041143995    12.5517534927328    15.7619767486311    12.2172038221044    13.9652791687812    16.7773336435092    14.5739765651185
"EBNA-3A"   13.5261288842902    13.6441695719583    12.2940498544562    10.3248767002703    10.4565252321896    10.2395951545488    11.3161568081138    8.01887155347027    10.8234681865165    10.2191057065881    10.486312096314 10.2628355595754    12.6789716681944    11.2474729408392
"BaRF1.1"   11.5143632366592    11.5247379629277    9.57131851390695    7.87214123495002    11.5746283416562    12.4036650041891    10.7584365787954    8.44013432267619    10.4466661892083    11.2394164309238    9.42736100308226    11.1087928510431    10.6301402787219    12.1435177805505
"BALF5" 11.2652146043959    10.733703589074 8.49883906996978    6.2215922129249 9.06100632059499    12.4205197833549    10.0478397441324    10.6507773464476    9.76010901842831    9.18953870315156    8.16433348137712    10.5985618763471    8.96195932055541    12.4050150570599
"BcRF1.2"   10.751155254366 10.5295782908455    9.33147507345346    6.62373032656138    9.64266498961866    10.3323612468993    9.11157065214385    6.5354202386595 10.1005870995364    9.45869565316021    8.45930769701399    9.59662767646299    6.16110648463473    10.6378103551596
"BBRF1" 11.1237305765991    11.0942012768623    8.93171114727267    7.79476909587258    10.1398466621808    9.93634727437349    9.1519159594182 7.00407059197787    9.9210595649652 10.0746243069256    8.53265706942628    9.34148547580504    13.1182763972876    10.7812718756883
"EBNA-1"    11.4044541396581    10.6587435006504    13.8908736119103    11.9039058574054    10.8169169512412    9.798691469002  12.7982051504752    12.5467186842168    12.1808079465559    10.1579084746448    12.0948549698248    11.1052599939321    15.5945833454739    12.0122613024627
"BGRF1/BDRF1"   11.643798810108 11.6954105540572    9.25101051522983    7.2474308881565 10.5786279726912    10.5357337425178    9.09477155628712    7.8609574972453 9.62841973972305    10.0675306679872    8.19625338829549    9.5437291206492 13.7534500437758    10.6743843485506
"BTRF1" 11.065885683419 11.1305639808595    9.83765410455105    7.12018772157739    11.085526603217 11.4613713478366    10.0801401022141    7.06135796902714    10.8224054867167    10.686011707017 9.49298319488775    10.6337453022771    6.83572873850483    11.7328760776643
"BNLF2b"    14.8731247882316    14.7063957258396    15.1371583788312    17.3731880547304    15.8753514928859    15.0388860726656    16.9663310081799    12.8217412473999    12.730643264106 15.6435192220812    12.2022048094347    14.3478360372367    16.5193182973491    14.9089638749887
"BNRF1" 12.7616872421229    12.7174263324682    10.910570031763 10.7457628638761    12.2832246424838    11.7738022067671    11.6300221007797    15.5136751962934    10.5375958168872    12.473664710412 11.4775911661836    12.0447502220917    11.9312684583932    12.3436687189333
```

Comment: Hey @vmicrobio, if you add the output from `dput(tpm.100)` to your question you will have a much better chance of getting a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you could follow [this tutorial](https://davetang.org/muse/2018/05/15/making-a-heatmap-in-r-with-the-pheatmap-package/) by Dave Tang:

```
install.packages(pheatmap)
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(tpm.100)
```

Also, [this tutorial](https://compgenomr.github.io/book/gene-expression-analysis-using-high-throughput-sequencing-technologies.html#computing-different-normalization-schemes-in-r) is worth a look as it describes a full RNA-Seq pipeline in detail, not just the visualisation.

Comment: thank you for your answer @jared_mamrot, pheatmap seems great with a lot of possibilities! Still I haven't a lisible plot <img src="https://ibb.co/yPKxpbC>

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I get using [jared_mamrot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12957340/jared-mamrot) recommandations:

```
install.packages("pheatmap")
library(pheatmap)

# load data and subset
data=read.table("/Users/vmicrobio/Desktop/tpm.100.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE,row.names = 1 )
head(data)

# data.matrix()
data_subset <- as.matrix((data), threshold = 10, p=0.2)
tpm=data.frame(data_subset)
tpm.log <- log2(tpm[,]+1)

# normalization
cal_z_score <- function(x){
  (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)
}
tpm.log_norm <- t(apply(tpm.log, 1, cal_z_score))

# heatmap
pheatmap(tpm.log_norm, main="test norm", fontsize_row=6, filename="/Users/vmicrobio/Desktop/heatmap_test.pdf")
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APZ8t.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Congrats - nice job!